# Identify checkout success page

Tags: magento-1.8

when i  echo

```
"Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getActionName();"
```

on

```
"checkout/onepage/success"
```

page it gives me values as "index".
As per url i suppose output should be "success".

I want to identify if current page is checkout success page, so i tried to use the above code, but it gives undesired output.

Comment: In my experience if you're having to test the name of a controller you're probably not approaching an issue correctly. What exactly are you trying to accomplish once you know it's the success page?

Comment: I wanted to implement Google trusted  Store Code, and for that their is 2 script code available. One code that is needed through out website, i have placed it on footer while other needs to be places on checkout success page. On testing i got error that more than once code was available. Thats why i need to identify checkout success page so that i can avoid loading the first code placed on footer section.

Comment: I figured as much. I will add an answer that includes adding a script block to the checkout success route only. This way no sniffing of controller actions required.

Answer (score 6):

Magento page layout is matching  with FullActionName().

`Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();`

If this code returns true

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName() === 'checkout_onepage_success'
```

it means that this page is the checkout success page

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @mbalparda indeed answers your original question. However, based on the comments, it sounds like what you really *need* is a layout.

If you placed the code in the `footer.phtml` template file you'll have a hard time removing it on the success page. In that case we'll create a layout instruction so that we can remove it once we're on the success page.

### 1. Create two static blocks

Name them `google-trusted-general` and `google-trusted-success`. Place your scripts (script tag and all) into each.

### 2. Update (or create) your local.xml theme layout

In your theme's layout folder add this to your `local.xml` file (if it doesn't exist, create it):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="cms/block" name="trusted">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>google-trusted-general</block_id></action>
            </block> 
        </reference>
    </default>
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <remove name="trusted"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="checkout.success">
            <block type="core/text" as="trusted" name="trusted">
                <block type="cms/block" name="trusted">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>google-trusted-success</block_id></action>
                </block> 
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
</layout>
```

This will add the script to the entire site and remove on the success page, displaying a new block.

Comment: This should be the way to go, but when the cache is onm the footer is cached and calling a remove `statement` may be useless. Or am I wrong?

Comment: That's a fantastic point

Comment: @marius moving it out of the footer would be harmless - I think i'll just do it that way!

Comment: Yep. Since is javascript....

Answer (score 0):

Use

> Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()

and there you will see the entire request and not only the action name.
Dont echo it but var_dump() it since its an array.

This can be useful too:

```
**
 * get Controller name
 */
$this->getRequest()->getControllerName();

/**
 * get Action name, i.e. the function inside the controller
 */
$this->getRequest()->getActionName();

/**
 * get Router name
 */
$this->getRequest()->getRouteName();

/**
 * get module name
 */
$this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
```

from [here](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-controller-action-and-module-name-in-template-file/).