# Magento2 check in template if page is homepage

Tags: magento2, home, page, conditional-loading

How would I check directly in a .phtml template if the requested page is homepage?

I would like to add conditionally a class to a given container

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check Ishomepage in Magento 2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93148/how-to-check-ishomepage-in-magento-2)

Comment: but as I see over there the code logic is inside class and on the other side the same template are used by different blocks in my case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to check if page is home page](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111031/best-way-to-check-if-page-is-home-page)

Comment: Those are not exact duplicates. Here it is asked for the .phtml - and Phil's answer is good for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're checking which page is the homepage from your template then you're approaching Magento templating and layout incorrectly.

My approach generally is to create a **block** of type **core/template** and add that via **layout** to the correct **layout handle**.

More information can be found at this answer:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/30562/336

A deeper explanation of this misunderstood concept can be found at my blog here:

https://blog.philwinkle.com/the-most-misunderstood-concept-in-magento/

For an even deeper dive into Magento Layout read Alan Storm's book on the topic:

http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout

Comment: The question is asking about Magento 2, but these answers all relate to Magento 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use instance of \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http in your class constructor. If you are in a controller you don't need to do it.

You can already access it like this `$request = $this->getRequest()`

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    ...
    $this->_request = $request;
}
```

Then you can check if is homepage or categorypage or productpage like this:

```
if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
    //you are on the homepage
}
if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
    //you are on the product page
}
if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
    //you are on the category page
}
```

Otherwise directly use in phtml file using object manager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
```